# Is it possible to return all documents in a SharePoint 2010 Search Index?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I would like to execute a search where all documents are returned, so that end user can browse the documents by applying different refiners.

Is this possible?

I've tried leaving the search box empty and clicking search, but a message pops up "Please enter one or more search words".

I've also tried to open result.aspx without any query parameters, I then get this mesage "No results are available. Either no query is specified, or the query came from advanced search (Federated Webparts do not support Advanced Search queries)."

Anyone?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter put a hash tag (#) (or pound symbol, whatever you call it) you will return all the items in the SharePoint search.

You could also do a search: IsDocument:1

Jason